# Low load rotor copper losses versus full load rotor copper losses

Tags: induction-motor

i made a table to try to understand why an induction motor copper losses increase with an increase in the rotor slip resistance. For the sake of understanding I ignored the copper winding resistance.

So, as the rotor slip resistance increases at lower loads due to large slip, which would reduce the amount of current that can pass through the rotor circuit and vice versa.

And, since the relation of the copper losses is directly proportional to the square of the current and the slip rotor resistance.

It's clearly that increasing the rotor slip resistance does not increase rotor copper losses.

[image]

However, the below says the opposite

[image]

Source:

Electric Machinery and Transformers

Bhag S. Guru

Department of Electrical and Computer Engineering

Kettering University

Oxford University Press  2001

[image: ISBN 97X-0-19-5 13x00-0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guru is writing about the physical resistance of the rotor bars (winding). When considering rotor copper loss, you must consider that the resistance in the rotor portion of the equivalent circuit is R2 + R2(1-s)/s. Power dissipated by R2 is the copper losses. The power dissipated in R2(1-s)/s is the power converted to mechanical energy. The physical resistance of the rotor bars (winding) does not change with slip, only R2(1-s)/s changes. R2(1-s)/s is not a physical resistance, but a construct of the equivalent circuit used to represent the energy conversion.

Comment: Perfect explanation thank you.

Comment: I got the difference, for instance, for a fixed slip of s = 0.05, fixed voltage = 100 V. If R2 = 1 ohm, then R2 + R2(1-s)/s = 20 ohm and I2 = 5 A and the copper losses are = 25 W. However, if R2 = 2 ohm, then R2 + R2(1-s)/s = 40 ohm and I2 = 2.5 A and the copper losses are = 12.5 W. although we increased the rotor copper resistor, the copper losses reduce with an increase in the rotor resistance. Am I still confused?

Comment: Picking arbitrary values for three of the seven or so values of equivalent circuit parameters may not provide a reasonable example. In addition, ignoring the rest of the equivalent circuit also distorts the results. The equivalent circuit can be simplified, but extreme simplification and unrealistic parameter values yield odd results. If you start with equivalent circuit values for a practicable motor, you can change the value of one element at a time and see the effect for values in the normal range and also see what happens with extreme variation and circuit simplification.